# Intellij IDEA doesn't detect changes

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Yesterday I refactored my project and I changed layout of my packages (I moved some packages into another packages, created new packages etc). But now, when I try to run JUnit test I get `NoSuchMethodError` on methods which name is changed after refactoring. Also, when I change other code in methods, IDEA still running old code.. I tried to run "Invalidate caches" in File menu, also I tried to reboot computer - no result. Where can be problem?

EDIT: Yesterday after moving packages IDEA doesn't correctly change package declarations in `.java` files, so I changed them by hand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have two suggestions you could try here

- Edit your test configuration(s) and ensure that they're pointing to what you expect them to.  I've sometimes seen a refactoring not being picked up in the run configuration and I've had to manually change it
- Less likely to work, but try to synchronize your project: File->Synchronize. Do this at the highest level of your project

With regards to your edit - I've not seen this myself.  Whenever I've renamed or moved files (including packages) these changes have been correctly applied to all applicable files.  Are you refactoring with Refactor>Move / Refactor->Copy ?

Comment: This didn't help me. I am not even refactoring the code. 
I am just writing a code to make my test pass. But that code is not reflecting when i run the test from intelliJ. But, if i run "mvn clean install" and then run test in intelliJ it is working fine.

Answer (score 8):

VCS -> Refresh File Status solved this for me, when Intellij suddenly stopped noticing changes.

Answer (score 7):

What I did in order to solve the issue was to "invalidate and Restart":

[image]

File -> invalidate and Restart

Answer (score 4):

**SOLUTION:**

Error magically gone after 2 things:

1. I imported this project into eclipse and run JUNit test from eclipse. Then I returned to IDEA and deleted all Eclipse specific files.
2. I synchronized my project (File->Synchronize).

I don't know what actually was the solution of problem, but for suggestions I accept @SeanLandsman's answer

Answer (score 4):

Answer to an old question, but:

If you're using a Run Configuration, make sure in the "Before Launch" section of the "Run/Debug Configurations" dialog, you have added "Build". It seems to get removed from this dialog sometimes, even if you have it added in the default settings.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the entire content of the classes dir worked for me

Comment: Strangely enough that is the only thing that worked in my case, I deleted the entire class file and added basically the same thing again. And it only glitched up on me once, Intelij is the ideal IDE, 99.99% percent of the time for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another root-cause can be:

If you are using Lombok, try to deinstall/reinstall the Intellij Lombok Plugin.

That solved such a strange behaviour in my case!

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting .class file of class where nosuchmethod error is throwing, and recompile.

Comment: In my case, that resulted in the class not being compiled at all. So I had to run build anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Found this posting from IntelliJ and Maven not finding POM changes. Had to Reload All Maven projects to fix it. Maven panel, upper left corner circle of arrows button.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue running with WSL2.   I know I have problems with my environment but the way I got this to work was to add a build step to run a maven goal of clean before the build.

Configuration: Edit
Choose your configuration to edit
Modify Options
Before Launch
Add Before Launch Task
Run Maven Goal
In the command Line field enter in "clean"

I have to rebuild everything, but it works. If you are running tests, you most likely need to update your test template, so it works every time when you choose to run a subset of test.   You most likely will need to delete all the existing build configurations for your unit test so it will take in the new test template.

In the same Run/Debug Configurations Windowchoose the Edit Configuration Templates

[image]

Choose your test framework.  Mine is JUnit,   Then follow the same steps as above

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution:

- Go to **Run/Debug Configuration**
- Click on **"Modify options"**
- Tick the **"Add before launch task"** option
- Add **"Build Project"** as new task

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me.

In IntelliJ IDEA,

1. Right click on the project.
2. Select Git -> Show History.
3. Opens "Version Control"

Then you can navigate to Local Changes Tab.

Comment: What?! What's that got to do with this?!