# intellij idea suddenly stopped noticing changes

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Related Questions:

[Intellij IDEA doesn't detect changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020432/intellij-idea-dont-detect-changes)

How to clean project cache in Intellij idea like Eclipse's clean?

The answers does not seem to work.

File -> Synchronize, VCS -> Refresh File Status, File -> Invalidate Cache seem to be good solutions, but they do not work at all.

Also one of the file is greyed out just yesterday. But I am seeing this problem for two weeks now.

I have rebuild the project. Still it does not work.

Please help. I am using intelliJ version.

Should I delete .IntelliJIdea13>system>log?

Please look at this link too:

https://github.com/pantsbuild/pants/issues/564

I did change the folder in which my project file exists, and created a new folder with the same name and update from the SVN

"What seems to be happening is that when you don't use the --idea-project-dir override, a new directory with the name of the project is created.

./pants goal idea ... --idea-project-name=zun123463

Generated IntelliJ project in /Users/zundel/Development/java/.pants.d/idea/idea/IdeaGen/zun123463

When you use the --idea-project-dir flag, you don't get a separate directory to hold the .iml files:

./pants goal idea ... --idea-project-name=zun123463 --idea-project-dir=squarepants/idea

Generated IntelliJ project in /Users/zundel/squarepants/idea/

I'm not sure what is the best course of action. On the one hand, the current behavior gives the user exactly what they ask for so maybe we should leave --idea-project-dir alone. On the other hand, it doesn't act the same as if you don't specify the flag and sets you up for failure. I'm going to propose a patch that tacks on --idea-project-name onto the end of --idea-project-dir.
"

is this the problem?

How do I fix it?

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be solved by deleting logs, caches, indexes and temp files at the IntelliJIdea13/system folder

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem last night and it was a pain.  My solution was to delete the `.idea` folder, invalidate caches, and reimport the project.  I thought the problem was related to the `scala` plugin, but I guess its not.

Comment: Thanks mechko, I resolved part of the problem by deleting logs,caches and temp folders at  .IntelliJIdea13>system folder.